# Can a use case be called in data layer in context of Clean Architecture?

Tags: android, clean-architecture

I have read a couple articles about clean architecture concepts [here](https://proandroiddev.com/clean-architecture-data-flow-dependency-rule-615ffdd79e29) and [here](https://proandroiddev.com/a-guided-tour-inside-a-clean-architecture-code-base-48bb5cc9fc97) and others.
I think I understand what is going on but they didn't solve the question that I have.
*I wonder if a use case can be called from data layer. if so, how? if not why?*

**UPDATE**:
what I am trying to do is to track what is happening during each usecase with a *event usecase*. Sometimes, I need to collect those info in data layer as well.
Let's say I have

> CollectEventUseCase

for that *event usecase*. I want to track if a person data lookup from network was fail but successful from database during the LookupPersonUsecase and I want to collect that information that lookup was failed from network but successful from database, is this a bad idea to call CollectEventUseCase in data layer? is this okay solution to this case? or whatelse should be the right approach?

Comment: Is the `CollectEventUseCase` purpose to mainly just log events to some cloud service for telemetry of your app?  If so, I wouldn't necessarily call it a use case as much as just a logger.

Comment: 'CollectEventUseCase' actually does mainly four tasks (I grouped them since they all work relevently together). 1. collect regular events 2. save regular events to database 3. collect urgent events 4. send urgent events to cloud service

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer** - No, in a CLEAN architecture the data layer should not be calling through to a use case as it would be breaking the [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Data layer should only be concerned with data, not business logic which lives in a use case.

**Long Answer**

One main reason for implementing a CLEAN architecture is for implementing separation of concerns, meaning each layer addresses a specific concern in your app. Expanding on the photo in [domain layer Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide/domain-layer), an app architecture might look like the picture below.

[image]

Where the domain layer would contain all of the business logic for presentation and use cases which can communicate with different sources in the data layer.

The data layer exists to serve as an abstraction over where data is coming from and that should be its only responsibility. Most apps data layers are fetching data from the network and then caching that data in a local database. So to best separate the concerns, a use case should only be concerned about interacting with different sources from the data layer and any business logic.

Comment: I am sorry for late response, but could you take a look at my question again that I just updated?